# How to test a routed page with Python webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, single-page-application

I'm new here and new to Selenium. I have an SPA that is written in AngularJS.  I'm trying to test a view with Python webdriver but it can't find the elements in the routed page.  My question is how can I test the routed page?

view`<div id ="form" align="center" ng-controller = "BP">
    <input id = "topNumber" ng-model ="topNum" placeholder="Top Number" type ="number" class="form"/>
    <br><br>
    <input id = "botNumber" ng-model="bottomNum" placeholder="Bottom Number" type="number" class ="form"/>
    <br><br>
    <button class ="form" id ="bp_enter" ng-click="write(topNum, bottomNum)">Enter</button>
</div>`
 code

current python attempt

```
from selenium import webdriver
path = r'C:\Users\Mason\Desktop\chromedriver.exe'

var = webdriver.Chrome(path)

var.get("http://localhost/PhpProject30/index.php#!/")


var.find_element_by_id('home').click()
var.find_element_by_id('bp_btn').click()
var.find_element_by_id('BP_enter_btn').click()


var.get("http://localhost/PhpProject30/index.php#!/BP_Enter")

var.find_element_by_id('bp_enter').click()
```

Comment: What happens when you execute your code? Do you get an error? If so update the question with the error/exception

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Selenium was executing to fast.  It was looking for an element in the view before it the view loaded.  I put a pause in there to give the view sometime and it worked like charm.

All I did was the following

```
import time

time.sleep(.5)
```